# Proving Vectors are linearly dependent in certain fields

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that any 2 vectors in $F$, an $F$-vector space, are linearly dependent, and that any 3 vectors are linearly dependent in $F^2$.

My problem is I don't know if I can assume that $F$ is like a "number line" (in which I would easily be able to do the proof), and similarly with $F^2$.

I keep thinking about the Reals, but how would I prove such a statement for all $F$ and $F^2$?

Comment: Yes, you can think of $F$ as a number line, regardless of the field $F$ (of course this is just a mental picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1$ be a basis for $F$ as an $F$-vector space.  Then every element of $F$ is $f x_1$ for some $f \in F$.  Let $f_1 x_1$ and $f_2 x_1$ be two nonzero, linearly independent elements of $F$.  Then $a_1 f_1 x_1 + a_2 f_2 x_1 = 0$ if and only if $a_1 = a_2 = 0$.  But if we set $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = -\frac{f_1}{f_2}$ (which is defined because $f_2 \neq 0$ and nonzero because $f_1 \neq 0$), we have $f_1 x_1 - \frac{f_1}{f_2} f_2 x_1 = 0$, a contradiction.  Therefore, $f_1 x_1$ and $f_2 x_1$ are not linearly independent.

The three vector case is the same argument with a little more detail checking.